# Getting DNN error after login as host in DNN site

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

I am getting DNN Error while login as host/admin but it is working fine without login as well as login as user. So, what will be the issue? I am really struggled to resolve this for past two days but no improvement.

Comment: How to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please mention your error message in your question. You are written your thoughts. We need questions, not thoughts.

Comment: Hi Dexterity, my error message "An unexpected  error has occurred"

Comment: That error message isn't helpful.  Try looking in the /Portals/_default/Logs folder for the latest log file.  Try finding the stack trace of the error based on the timestamp.  Also, what version of DNN are you using?